# How can I display a copy of an HTML <div> with 80% of its actual size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display a `<div>` with all of its inside content as preview, meaning that I have to create the same `<div>` element again with different width height values, and the image (eg background images) with reduced sizes as well.

Is there an easy way to do this? Or do I have to create new images and new HTML code for this?

#### Edit

I tried the CSS `zoom` property which only works for IE and Chrome 8. I need it to work on all common browsers: FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome and IE.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think there’s an easy way to do this in CSS. The new [`background-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) property might help with background images, but it’s not widely supported yet.

The “easiest” way (where by “easy” I mean “involves you writing the least amount of complicated code”) would be to get the HTML and CSS you want previewed to be rendered by an actual browser’s rendering engine, and get that rendering saved out as an image.

Not sure if that’ll work in the context you’re working in though.

Answer (score 3):

This maybe possible only in Internet Explorer with IE-specific "zoom" property.

For other browsers you can easily resize elements, fonts, images, objects, but not background images. For background images you will need set of actually resized images.

Comment: I need to make a preview of a whole website page with many bg-images and many css declarations, Zoom property is what I need, but as you said it only works on IE and chrome

Comment: @wael34218 then forget about it. Just create screenshot and show it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried applying a style that makes everything inside the div 80%? For example:

```
.preview, .preview * {
  font-size: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: what about images, and background images?

Comment: You can set the width and height of images via CSS that are embedded in the document, however background images would have to be resized either using something like PHPthumb or via CSS3's background-size, although CSS3 isn't widely supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the div with a parent div then give a static width and height to parent div then set % width and height the target div.